# Query NPS Radius SQL log for reject events

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to have a SQL query to find only radius reject events (type=3). The previous row is also required to know the user name that was rejected.

Data looks like this:

| id | timestamp | NPS_Svr | Packet_Type | Description | User-Computer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27949 | 1:25:46 PM | SVR1 | 2 | Access Accept | NULL |
| 27948 | 1:25:46 PM | SVR1 | 1 | Access Request | user1 |
| 27947 | 1:25:36 PM | SVR1 | 3 | Access REJECT | NULL |
| 27946 | 1:25:36 PM | SVR1 | 1 | Access Request | user1 |
| 27945 | 1:25:33 PM | SVR3 | 2 | Access Accept | NULL |
| 27944 | 1:25:33 PM | SVR3 | 1 | Access Request | user2 |
| 27943 | 1:25:21 PM | SVR3 | 3 | Access REJECT | NULL |
| 27942 | 1:25:21 PM | SVR3 | 1 | Access Request | user2 |

```
select * 
from accounting_data
where packet_type=3
```

Returns the reject rows but I also need the previous row from the same NPS Server to know the user name that was rejected.

The server is MS SQL 2014.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand previous row it's
according to sort order of id columns,
So I suggest to self join by id-1

```
SELECT main.*,past.user_computer FROM (
select m.*,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY nps_svr ORDER BY id ) as RnKSer 
from accounting_data m  
) main left join (SELECT nps_svr,RnKSer-1 as PastRnKSer,user_computer  
FROM (
select m.*,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY nps_svr ORDER BY id ) as RnKSer 
from 
accounting_data m  
) prev ) past on main.nps_svr=past.nps_svr and RnKSer=PastRnKSer
where packet_type=3
ORDER BY 1
```

[image]

Comment: This should work unless another radius server logs data at the same time. Is there an easy way to get the previous entry for the same server?

Comment: OK, I added RANK by server name for creating inner index for each server and added server name to join. Now the query will return past row for each server